# How to pass parameters from spring boot to spring batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I search a solution to how passing springboot parameters to my spring batch job and then get the value of parameter in my writer. when I load the key in my writer is still null.
Somebody can help me please ?

```
    @GetMapping("/load/{id}")
    public BatchStatus load (@PathVariable String id) throws 
    JobExecutionException {
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .addString("key", id).toJobParameters();

        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);

        return jobExecution.getStatus();
    }
```

Here is my Batch code configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    @Value("${path.to.react.file}")
    private Resource resource;

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Value("#{jobParameters['key']}")
    private String pathToFile;

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("readCSVFilesJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<UserDTO, 
    UserDTO>chunk(100)
                .reader(Reader.reader(resource))
                .processor(new Processor())
                .writer(new Writer(userDao))
                .build();
       }
   }
```

And my Writer

```
@StepScope
public class Writer implements ItemWriter<UserDTO> {


private  UserDao userDao;

@Value("#{jobParameters['key']}")
private String key;

public Writer(UserDao userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;

}

@Override
public void write(List<? extends UserDTO> items) throws Exception {
    userDao.writePnoFile(items);
}
```

}

Comment: Take a look at how to bind job parameters in item readers/writers here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested to integrate the annotation @StepScope. but it doesn't work. I updated my code can you help me please.

Comment: you need to add `@Component` otherwise your writer will not be declared a spring bean and the step scope will not be applied.

Comment: yes i already tried to do this but it the same. :(

Answer (score 2):

Add `@Scope("step")` to your writer and then inject parameters via `@Value` annotation:

```
@Value("#{jobParameters['key']}")
String key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample doesn't work cause you instantiate your writer

```
.writer(new Writer(userDao))
```

and then, all your annotations become useless (@Stepcope, @Values ...).
You need to let spring instantiate it for you by using @Autowired on writer field of your config.